# swagger.yaml: how to generate a ResponseEntity with `InputStreamResource` type。

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger-codegen to generate JAVA class.

I want to generate a class with  ResponseEntity with `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>` .

For example:

```java
ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> pmml(@RequestParam(value = "modelUuid") String modelUuid);
```

I use the below yaml to generate JAVA class.

```
paths:
  /report:
    get:
      summary: Returns the report in the PDF format
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A PDF file
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

but it only generate the java class as below:

```java
ResponseEntity<File> report();
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?